# Wrong constellations of echoed rows in while loop with fetched array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem concerning wrong constellations of echoed rows in a while loop with a `mysql_fetch_array`.

Please bear in mind that it's an old environement and `mysqli` can't be used.

In the first step, three rows are gained by a mysql query:

```html
$row1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($aid_query)) {
    $row1[] = $row['aid'];}
$det_query = mysql_query("SELECT det1.baseData AS det11, det2.baseData AS det22, det3.baseData AS det33
FROM (SELECT baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '20' AND aid IN(". implode(",",$row1). ")) AS det1,
(SELECT baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '25' AND aid IN(". implode(",",$row1). ")) AS det2,
(SELECT baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '40' AND aid IN(". implode(",",$row1). ")) AS det3
");
```

In the second step, the results should be echoed:

```html
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($det_query)) {
echo $row2['det11']."&nbsp;From:&nbsp;".$row2['det22']."&nbsp;To:&nbsp;".$row2['det33']."&nbsp;lorem ipsum";
echo '</br>';
}
```

That's the point where the problem arises.
The `$aid_query` or rather `$row1` from the first step contains five (varies depending on selections in relation with `$aid_query`) id's (e.g. 500, 503 etc.).
So, the rows det11, det22 and det33 contain five values each.
But instead of echoing five lines like

```html
det11[first value], det22[first value], det33[first value] 
det11[second value], det22[second value], det33[second value]
```

etc., it echoes 25 scenarios with all possible compilations.
This means, that all five values of each row are echoed combined with all five values of each other row.
So, for example:

```html
det11[first value] det22[first value] det33[first value]
det11[second value] det22[first value] det33[first value]
det11[third value] det22[first value] det33[first value]
det11[fourth value] det22[first value] det33[first value]
det11[fifth value] det22[first value] det33[first value]

det11[first value] det22[second value] det33[first value]
det11[second value] det22[second value] det33[first value]
det11[third value] det22[second value] det33[first value]
det11[fourth value] det22[second value] det33[first value]
det11[fifth value] det22[second value] det33[first value]

...

det11[first value] det22[first value] det33[fifth value]
det11[second value] det22[first value] det33[fifth value]
det11[third value] det22[first value] det33[fifth value]
det11[fourth value] det22[first value] det33[fifth value]
det11[fifth value] det22[first value] det33[fifth value]

...
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could understand as well as explain the error.
I think it has something to do with the query of the first step, I tried it with `UNION` as well as `JOIN`, but no difference arised.

Comment: Can u create a sqlfiddle and ignore php for starters

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem (that I can see) with the PHP.

The issue is the query... it's returning the result we expect, since the query is generating a Cartesian product of the rows returned from the three inline views (`det1`, `det2`, `det3`).

Your query is using old-school comma syntax for join operation, but there are no join predicates (conditions) which limit which rows are matched with which rows.

That is, your query is performing the equivalent of CROSS JOIN operations, of the form:

```
  SELECT det1.baseData AS det11
       , det2.baseData AS det22
       , det3.baseData AS det33
    FROM ( SELECT baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '20' AND aid IN (,,,)
         ) det1
   CROSS
    JOIN ( SELECT baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '25' AND aid IN (,,,)
         ) det2
   CROSS
    JOIN ( SELECT baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '40' AND aid IN (,,,)
         ) det3
```

---

If `det1`, `det2` and `det3` return *m*, *n* and *o* rows respectively, the total number of rows returned by the query will be the product of *m*, *n* and *o*.  Or, 5 x 5 x 5 = 125.

This is expected behavior.

---

What resultset did you expect to be returned?

I'm expecting that you want the rows to be matched on the `aid` values. The quick (but possibly incomplete) fix on the query is to add matching of `aid` values.

For example:

```
  SELECT det1.baseData AS det11
       , det2.baseData AS det22
       , det3.baseData AS det33
    FROM ( SELECT aid, baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '20' AND aid IN (,,,)
         ) det1
    JOIN ( SELECT aid, baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '25' AND aid IN (,,,)
         ) det2
      ON det2.aid = det1.aid
    JOIN ( SELECT aid, baseData FROM xy WHERE z = '40' AND aid IN (,,,)
         ) det3
      ON det3.aid = det1.aid
```

---

I say that "fix" is potentially incomplete, because if a particular value of `aid` is "missing" from any of the inline views, that query won't return a row for that `aid`.

That is if the row `aid=500,z=20` exists, but a matching row `aid=500,z=40` does *not* exist, then `aid=500` row won't be returned by the query, because of the inner join operation.

If you have 5 values in the `aid` list, and you want to return 5 rows, you would need to write the query slightly differently. You could "implode" that array of values into an inline view. Assuming that `(aid,z)` is UNIQUE in `xy`...

Something like this:

```
  SELECT det1.baseData AS det11
       , det2.baseData AS det22
       , det3.baseData AS det33
    FROM ( SELECT '500' AS aid 
           UNION ALL SELECT '503'
           UNION ALL SELECT '505'
           UNION ALL SELECT '507'
           UNION ALL SELECT '509'
         ) q
    LEFT
    JOIN xy det1 ON det1.aid = q.aid AND det1.z = '20'
    LEFT
    JOIN xy det2 ON det2.aid = q.aid AND det2.z = '25'
    LEFT
    JOIN xy det3 ON det3.aid = q.aid AND det3.z = '40'
   ORDER BY q.aid
```